# Find bases of matrix without multiplying

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is related to a solved problem in Gilbert Strang's 'Introduction to Linear Algebra'(Chapter 3,Question 3.6A, Page 190).

> Q) Find bases and dimensions for all four fundamental subspaces of A if you know that
>
> $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\2 & 1 & 0 \\ 5 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 0 & 5\\0 & 0 & 1 & 6\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} = LU = E^{-1}R$

Answer given in the text:

> This matrix has pivots in columns $1$ and $3$. Its rank is $r=2$.
>
> Column space : Basis $(1,2,5)$ and $(0,1,0)$ from $E^{-1}$

Why does he choose the first two columns of $E^{-1}$ as a basis ? If anything, the pivot columns of $R$ are an obvious choice for basis.

Comment: What are "the four fundamental (?) subspaces"? And of whom? And what has that matrix A to do with all this?

Comment: @DonAntonio I just wrote the portion of the problem from the text which raised the question in my mind. The question is related to the matrix $A$ which decomposes as shown. Does that help ? As for four fundamental subspaces, they refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of the product $E^{-1}R$ as the composition of linear applications, then $E^{-1}$ acts "last" and its columns determine somehow the image of $E^{-1}R$ (of course, it also depends on $R$).

More generally, for any functions from any sets that you can compose (assuming $Im(g) \subset D(f)$ where $D(f)$ is the domain where f is defined) then $Im(f \circ g) = f(Im(g)) \subset Im(f)$ because by definition

$Im(f \circ g) = \{ f(g(x)) \mid x \in D(g)\} = \{ f(y) \mid y \in Im(g) \} \subset \{ f(z) \mid z \in D(f) \}$

If $g$ is a constant function, so is $f \circ g$, and even if the image of $f$ can be very large, the image of $f \circ g$ is just a singleton. On the other hand, if $g$ is identity, then $Im(f \circ g) = Im(f)$ is maximal. You can have every cases between.

More specifically here in a linear setting, where $R : \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ and $E^{-1} : \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$,
$Im(E^{-1}R)=E^{-1}(ImR)=E^{-1}(span\{Re_1,Re_2,Re_3,Re_4\})$ if $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R^4}$. If one writes $(e'_1,e'_2,e'_3)$ for the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, since the last element of each columns is zero in $R$ (in other words : the last line is null), this shows that $Im(R) \subset span\{e'_1,e'_2\}$ and $rank(R) \leq 2$. But the rank of $R$ is at least $2$ (first and last column are free e.g), hence it is exactly $2$, and $Im(R) = span\{e'_1,e'_2\}$.

Finally, $Im(E^{-1}R)=span\{E^{-1}(e'_1),E^{-1}(e'_2)\}$ which are precisely the two first columns of $E^{-1}$.

Comment: If the columns of $E^{-1}$ determine the image, why should only the *first* two columns determine the image i.e why should it be $span\{(1,2,5),(0,1,0)\}$? Why not its last two columns $span\{(0,0,1),(0,1,0)\}$?

Comment: when I say that, I mean you can always choose among these columns to build a base of $Im(E^{-1}R)$. But it depends on R : if R was the identity for example (let's say now R is a square matrix), then the basis is generated by the three columns of $E^{-1}$, and if $R$ is null, then $E^{-1}R=0$ and you could say that it is an empty basis. And you can have all cases between. So the actual formula is $Im(E^{-1}R)=E^{-1}(ImR)$. Or here you can see that $Im(R)$ is generated by $e_1=(1,0,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1,0)$, so $Im(E^{-1}R)=span\{E^{-1}(e_1),E^{-1}(e_2)\}$ which are the two first columns

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and add the content from your  comment so that the answer feels complete ?

Comment: is it clearer like that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the right matrix, you'll see that

1. It conflates the 2-dimensional subspace generated by $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0)\}$ into the
   1-dimensional subspace generated by $\{(1,0,0)\}$, because it's first two columns are linearly dependent. In particular, it maps vectors of the form $(3x,-x,0,0)$ to the zero vector, i.e. $\ker A \supset \{(3,-1,0,0)\}$. Columns $1,3,4$ are also obviously linearly dependent, and that yields $\ker A \supset \{5,0,6,-1\}$.
2. It's range (i.e. what you call column space I think) is generated by $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$, because it's bottom row is all zeros.

The left matrix is invertible (lower triangular matrix, non-zero diagonal), and it follows that

1. $\textrm{rng } A = \textrm{span} \{(1,2,5),(0,1,0)\}$. This is simply the *image* of the range of the right matrix under the left matrix. This is easy to find because the right matrix's image is created by two canonical basis vectors, so we just had to pick the corresponding columns of the left matrix.
2. $\textrm{ker } A \supset \textrm{span} \{(3,-1,0,0),(5,0,6,-1)\}$. And because of the dimension theorem, we can conclude from (1) that in fact $\textrm{ker } A = \textrm{span} \{(3,-1,0,0),(5,0,6,-1)\}$.

Comment: I am afraid I do not follow your answer. You seem to have first and second matrices reversed. Also, I am not familiar with the terminology of $ker$ and $rng$.

Comment: @curryage I don't think so, but it said "second" in one sentence where it should have said "first". Replaced by "left" and "right", since that's less ambiguous - "first" and "second" could refer to the location in the product *or* to the application order.